# Show that the product of Sorgenfrey line is regular.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ be Sorgenfrey line, show that $(\mathbb R^2,\tau_1):=(\mathbb R,\tau)\times (\mathbb R,\tau)$ is regular.

I am struggling in this problem, and haven't made much progress. Please give me some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, arbitrary products of regular spaces are regular. The central point of this result is that if $A_i \subseteq X_i$ for $i \in I$, then $\overline{\prod_{i \in I} A_i } = \prod_{i \in I} \overline{A_i}$.

For this particular space, let $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and suppose that $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $(x_1,x_2)$ in $( \mathbb R^2 , \tau_1 )$.  Then there must be $y_1 > x_1$, $y_2 > x_2$ such that $V = [ x_1 , y_1 ) \times [ x_2 , y_2 ) \subseteq U$.  Note that both $[ x_1 , y_1 )$ and $[ x_2 , y_2 )$ are clopen in the Sorgenfrey line, and so it follows that $V$ is clopen in $( \mathbb R^2 , \tau_1 )$: $$\overline{V} = \overline{ [x_1,y_1) \times [ x_2,y_2 ) } = \overline{ [x_1,y_1) } \times \overline{ [ x_2,y_2) } = [ x_1 , y_1 ) \times [ x_2,y_2) = V.$$ Thus $( x_1,x_2 ) \in V = \overline{V} \subseteq U$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have reached the definition of regular space...

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ: _Regularity_ is equivalent to "for any $x \in X$ and any open $U \subseteq X$ containing $x$ there is an open $V \subseteq X$ with $x \in V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U$." Often this is the easier characterization to actually prove. A proof of the equivalence can be found in almost any topology text; in Munkres's _Topology_ it is Lemma 31.1(a).